# A Tricky sum to evaluate (Haldane)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, summation, integrable-systems

I'm trying to find a way to evaluate this sum (found by Haldane in Phys. Rev. Lett. 60, 635 (1988): 
$$S_{pq}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} z^{nJ} (1-z^{n})^{p-1}(1-z^{-n})^{q-1}$$
with $z= e^{\frac{2i\pi}{N}}$ and $0\leq J\leq N$
if someone have an idea, let me know, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You can use the [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement) and then simplify back with the N-th roots of the unit $\exp{(\frac{2i\pi}{N})}$.